# URL problem with product on front page

Tags: magento-1.7, product, ce-1.7.0.2, url

On the front page, I have a few "top seller" products. They respond by URL such as : www.website.com/bed-1546.html and www.website.com/chair-1284.html
When I click on those links, the product is not loaded, but I do not get a 404.

If I go to www.website.com/bedrooms/bed/bed-1546.html or www.website.com/livingroom/chair-1284.html , the products load correctly.

If I go back to www.website.com/bed-1546.html the product loads, until I visit another product, then it doesn't load again.

The website is using Magento 1.7.0.2.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check your php/magento error log page? Are you display category information on this page?

Comment: @R.S : no error displayed on the page. The menu loads and the breadcrumb too. No category information is displayed on the page.

Comment: Does the 'breadcrumb' contain the category name?

Comment: @R.S : No, it does not.

Comment: Also, if that helps, the URL Key in the product, is more like : bed-queen-gris

Answer (score 1):

This is no default behaviour by magento, so the only thought which comes in my mind is to disable all modules and turn them on, one by one, until it breaks again, then you know which modules this does.

And as always: [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)